# MVC Problems 16

Tags: c#

I am trying to post a part of my model for a view to action in another controller. I've tried to do it this way:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", new {createDto = Model.UserCreateDto}, FormMethod.Post))
{%>
      Form code here...
<%}%>
```

UserCreateDto is a part of my model and it's being filled in this form. I'm trying to pass it to "Register" action in UsersController:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UserCreateDto createDto)
The problem is that route value in Register action is null (createDto) after form submit. Maybe it is happening because route values are being attached to url before form submit event (and before model fields are filled).
Is there any way to do what I want?
UPDATE Here is the actual HTML code:

Имя пользователя

        
Пароль

        
E-mail

And here is the updated form code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{%>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(userCreateDto => Model.UserCreateDto.Username) %>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(userCreateDto => Model.UserCreateDto.Password) %>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(userCreateDto => Model.UserCreateDto.Email) %>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(userCreateDto => Model.UserCreateDto.Active) %>
    <%= Html.LabeledValidatedTextBoxFor(username => Model.UserCreateDto.Username, true) %>
    <%= Html.LabeledValidatedTextBoxFor(password => Model.UserCreateDto.Password, true)%>
    <%= Html.LabeledValidatedTextBoxFor(email => Model.UserCreateDto.Email, true)%>
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
<%}%>
```

Html.LabeledValidatedTextBoxFor is just my custon HTML helper.
Here is updated action signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UserCreateDto userCreateDto)
```

userСreateDto in this action is still null.http://www.media fire.com/file/5dcrv5zupy44c0i/A16.rar/file By the way, is there any way not to use hidden fields? They are not secure enough to pass through them user registration information.

Comment: if you trying to update data from hidden field then there is a problem. you can simply save data which you want to save and leave unwanted data, dont save them. you can Call UserCreateDto object from DB and pass only updated data and then save.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you're looking for is ModelBinding. If your UserCreateDto Model is complex enough, and by that I mean that it contains any other complex type inside, the DefaultModelBinder is not going to know how to fill your model. So you need to tell it explicitly how to map the values in your request to the Model you are expecting in the Register post method in your UserController.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) shows an example of how to do it in ASP.NET Core. I couldn't find the ASP.NET MVC official documentation but it's not so different than this.

Hope it helps!